# Add a "+" before each word in a string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I have created an array, "outData", using `javascript`, which looks like this:

[image: outdata array]

I'm now trying to:

1. loop through the outData array using jQuery each;
2. if the checkbox called 'bmm' is ticked, split the strings in the outData array into individual words;
3. add a "+" sign before each word;
4. finally, join the words with the plus signs into new strings (with a space between each word) and push into a new array called "outPlus".

I'm stuck on how to correctly add the plus sign before each word split from the strings.

My code currently looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#multi").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#output").empty();
        var array1 = [];
        var array2 = [];
        var array3 = [];
        $(".col1").each(function() {
            var word1 = $(this).val();
            if ( word1 !== "" ) {
                //word1 = word1.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                array1.push(word1);
            }
        });
        $(".col2").each(function() {
            var word2 = $(this).val();
            if ( word2 !== "" ) {
                //word2 = word2.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                array2.push(word2);
            }
        });
        $(".col3").each(function() {
            var word3 = $(this).val();
            if ( word3 !== "" ) {
                //word3 = word3.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                array3.push(word3);
            }
        });
        console.log(array1);
        console.log(array2);
        console.log(array3);
        var outData = [];
        var outPlus = [];
        $(array1).each(function( a, b ) {
            $(array2).each(function ( c, d ) {
                outData.push( b + " " + d );
                $(array3).each(function( e, f ) {
                    outData.push( b + " " + d + " " + f );
                });
            });
        });

        console.log(outData);

        if ( $("input[name='bmm']").prop("checked") == true ) {
            $(outData).each(function( g, h ) {
                outPlus.push( h.split(" ") );
            });

            console.log(outPlus);

            $(outPlus).each(function( i, j ) {
                    var output = j.replace(/(^|\s)/g, '$1+');
                    console.log(j);
                });
        }

        console.log(outPlus); //Uncaught TypeError: j.replace is not a function
    });

});
```

Current output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: j.replace is not a function
```

Desired output:

```
+used +car
+used +car +for +sale
+used +car +on +sale
etc...
```

Would be very grateful for help to produce the desired results. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `outPlus.push( h.split(" ").join("+") );` or `outPlus.push("+"+ h.split(" ").join("+") );` and remove this `$(outPlus).each(function( i, j ) {
        console.log("+" + j); //Produces output: "+used,car" etc...
    });`

Comment: Your logic seems a little off, but without seeing a full implementation it's hard to offer an improvement. My answer below should at least fix your immediate question.

Comment: @Anant This isn't quite right (I don't think). From this, I got: "used+car", "used+car+for+sale" etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `join()` at-once after `split()` to concatenate your array with `+` sign like below (easy).

```js
var outData = ['used car', 'used car for sale', 'used car on sale'];
   
var outPlus = [];

$(outData).each(function( g, h ) {
    outPlus.push("+"+h.split(" ").join(' +'));
});
console.log(outPlus);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Missing explanation. -1

Comment: Also, its better to use in-built looping mechanism. `Array.forEach` or `Array.map` should do it

Comment: @Anant This solved the original question, albeit with my nasty code. Cheers Anant.

Comment: @jonhendrix  glad to help you.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate to @[Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) would be to use `/(\w+)/g` regex.

Idea is to capture all words and replace them with `+$1`

**Get new array**

```js
var outData = [
  'used car',
  'used car for sale',
  'used car on sale',
  'used cars'
];

var output = outData.map(function(text) {
  return text.replace(/(\w+)/g, '+$1');
});

console.log(output);
```

---

**Replace original array**

```js
var outData = [
  'used car',
  'used car for sale',
  'used car on sale',
  'used cars'
];

outData.forEach(function(text, i, a) {
  a[i] = text.replace(/(\w+)/g, '+$1');
});

console.log(outData);
```

Comment: I edited your answer as the first snippet was outputting the wrong array :) I specifically used `\s` in my answer to find whitespace as `\w` will match punctuation like `,` or `!`, should those values appear in the original array. +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you can use a regular expression which follows any whitespace character, or the first character in the string, with a `+`. Try this:

```
$(outPlus).each(function(i, j ) {
  var output = j.replace(/(^|\s)/g, '$1+');
  console.log(j);
});
```

Here's a simplified example:

```js
var outData = [
  'used car',
  'used car for sale',
  'used car on sale',
  'used cars'
];

outData = outData.map(function(text) {
  return text.replace(/(^|\s)/g, '$1+');
});

console.log(outData);
```

Comment: Hi Rory - I'm sure that this does work but for the way in which I first created the outData array. I'm getting an error: "Uncaught TypeError: j.replace is not a function". Shall I paste in my full code snippet?

Comment: Yes please. It would be really helpful to see a more complete sample of your code, including how you create the DOM elements in step 1

Comment: Please use the `edit` button on your question add relevant code

Comment: That error seems to be because you've built the `outPlus` as a multi dimensional array, so `j` is an array, not a string, hence the error. I'm not even sure why you're doing that as `outPlus` seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: I built it that way because it was the only way I know (with limited knowledge) to concatenate three columns of words (.col1, .col2, .col3) in that specific way. outPlus was intended to be used to hold the words which are split from the outData array whilst prepending the plus signs. I'd be very happy to instead just split the strings from outData, add the plus signs, and then output them if you know how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136857/discussion-between-jonhendrix-and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 0):

You could output this on your last console.log line which would quickly change the output to what you want:

`console.log('+used,car,on,sale'.replace(/,/g, ' +'))`

It basically replaces the comma for a space and +, it's quick and easy, otherwise I would use `.split` method and split where the comma is and re-build from the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

Ther is no nead for jquery in this, try this:

If you don't want `es6` function syntax `=>` you can always use old `function`

```js
const data = [
  'used car',
  'used car for sale and something else'
]

const addPlus = data => data.replace(/\+?(\S+)/g, '+$1')

const addPlusInArray = array => array.map(addPlus)

console.log(addPlusInArray(data))
```

`.replace(`
`/\+?(\S+)/g` find any nont whitespace (optional + infront)
`'+$1'` replace with content of first capture group
`)`

`.map (`
`addPlus` result of this function caled with first argument as array element will become new content of new array
`)`